TYPO3V11 - fileReference: how to get files to create a ZIP
I’m relatively new to TYPO3 and currently managing a website built on this CMS. Since I have limited experience, I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance you can provide.
Thank you in advance!
I have array, use TYPO3-11.5.39, PHP-7.4.32.
<f:for each="{detail.images}" as="file">
<f:link.file file="{file.originalResource}" download="true" filename="{file.originalResource.properties.name}">Download file</f:link.file>                  
</f:for>



I need to convert this array to another array to create an archive. Here is my controller. The function is tested, the archive is created with constant values. But I can't get files from TYPO3.
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\extName\Controller;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference;
use ZipArchive;



class DownloadController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
    /**
     * Download action to create and download a zip file of images
     *
     * @return void
     */


    public function downloadZipAction(): void
    {

       
        $files = [];

        foreach ($this->detail->images as $fileReference) {
            if ($fileReference instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference) {
                $file = $fileReference->getOriginalResource();

                if ($file instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference) {
                    $identifier = $file->getIdentifier();
                    if ($identifier) {
                        $files[] = ['url' => $identifier];
                    }
                }
            }
        }




        $zipFileName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'images_') . '.zip';

        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        if ($zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE) {
            die('Could not create ZIP file.' );
        }

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $fileContent = @file_get_contents($file); /
            if ($fileContent === false) {
                echo "Failed to fetch file:";
                continue; 
            }
            $fileName = basename($file);
            if (!$zip->addFromString($fileName, $fileContent)) {
                echo "Failed to add file: $fileName";
            }
        }

        $zip->close();

        if (!file_exists($zipFileName) || filesize($zipFileName) == 0) {
            unlink($zipFileName); 
            die('Failed to create a non-empty ZIP file.  ' );
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="images.zip"');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipFileName));

        readfile($zipFileName);

        unlink($zipFileName);
        exit;
    }

}

My Fluid Template
                <f:link.action action="downloadZip" controller="Download" arguments="{detail: detail}" target="_blank">
                    Download Images as ZIP
                </f:link.action>

The controller works, but I get an empty archive.

Did you check if $files actually contains a file listing? You could modify it first to return a text/plain output and just emit all the filenames you gathered. Could be those are all empty, and thus an empty archive created. Then you'd have to check the foreach loop where maybe objects aren't set. Using xdebug or a debug(....) output within the loop can help. (Btw, you asked this in a facebook group, where I answered, why did you delete the post?)

Garvin, Thanks for your response on Facebook. However, I want to clarify that I didn’t delete the post—it made me feel a bit down, so I decided to leave the group.
Regarding the issue, everything else works fine except for the loop. The array remains empty because my loop isn’t functioning as expected.

You've to add the path of the file-storage before the file-path perhaps, which is 'fileadmin/' usually.

instead of collecting the identifiers as urls, try using $file->getForLocalProcessing(false); instead (with the "false" argument, that one is important). That one should give you the local system path.

Thanks for the answers, I get an empty array
PHP: die('Failed to create a non-empty ZIP file. ' .  $files );
output: Failed to create a non-empty ZIP file. Array.  How can I get any kind of FE-output from this object? TSFE?

Usually you can pass just the filepath to zip, you never have to create a stream with file_get_contents(), not sure if this is the source of the problem.

I think the issue was that you created an array with a "url" substructure, but when you iterated it, you did not utilize that. Also the file path was not using an absolute directory. Please see the updated code, I've placed "@NEW" annotation to see the difference to your implementation. Hope it helps!
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\extName\Controller;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage;
// @NEW: Import this for access to base directory
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Environment;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference;
use ZipArchive;

class DownloadController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
    /**
     * Download action to create and download a zip file of images
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function downloadZipAction(): void
    {
        $files = [];

        foreach ($this->detail->images as $fileReference) {
            if ($fileReference instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference) {
                $file = $fileReference->getOriginalResource();

                if ($file instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference) {
                    $identifier = $file->getIdentifier();
                    if ($identifier) {
                        // @NEW: No longer use 'url' subkey, and create a full path instread.
                            $files[] = Environment::getPublicPath() . $file->getOriginalFile()->getPublicUrl();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $zipFileName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'images_') . '.zip';
        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        if ($zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) !== TRUE) {
            die('Could not create ZIP file.' );
        }

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $fileContent = @file_get_contents($file);
            if ($fileContent === false) {
                echo "Failed to fetch file:";
                continue; 
            }
            $fileName = basename($file);
            if (!$zip->addFromString($fileName, $fileContent)) {
                echo "Failed to add file: $fileName";
            }
        }

        $zip->close();

        // @NEW: Split these checks, because 'unlink' on a non-existing otherwise
        if (!file_exists($zipFileName)) {
            die('Failed to create ZIP file.');
        }

        if (filesize($zipFileName) == 0) {
            unlink($zipFileName); 
            die('Failed to create a non-empty ZIP file.');
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="images.zip"');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipFileName));

        readfile($zipFileName);
        unlink($zipFileName);

        exit;
    }
}


I thank you for the answers. The problem is because this plugin was written before I did and I needed to extend the existing controllers. It doesn't work yet :) but I get data with arrays
